# ubunutu 20.04 power off not working on menu

Tags: 20.04, shutdown, logout

I was upgrade my ubuntu version 18.04 to 20.04 then facing some errors on it
here i asked it: [link](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/614792/authentication-is-required-to-create-a-color-profile-on-ubuntu-20-04)

it also fixed but now power off menu not working.

when i use logout then power off it will work but directly it is not working.

[image]